# Problem Passing token in Laravel passport

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, laravel-passport

Working on a Laravel application that requires authentication via passport from backend API. Am consuming a certain API that requires the user to be authenticated before parsing the data. When parsing the token from the frontend code I get error of Unauthenticated on by browser network tab but when I get a token directly on postman, it goes through.

Could I be missing something?

**Code that throws unauthenticated error**

```
   public function global_Curl_Post($data , $url)
    {
        $server = env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_NAME') !== null ? env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_NAME') : 'https://digitalapps*****.example.com';

        $accessToken = session('access_token');

        $headers = ["Accept:application/json",
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "Authorization:Bearer ".$accessToken
        ]; 

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($server.'/'.$url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        dd($response);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

**When I login on postman and copy the access_token in the code below it authenticates**

```
  public function global_Curl_Post($data , $url)
    {
        $server = env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_NAME') !== null ? env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_NAME') : 'https://digitalapps*****.example.com';

        $accessToken = session('access_token');

        //copy access_token from postman and paste directly
        $headers = ["Accept:application/json",
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "Authorization:Bearer "."yJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI.............."
        ]; 

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($server.'/'.$url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        dd($response);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Just to rule this out did you echo out the token and compare it to the one you entered manually in the second option above? Make sure there are no spaces or odd characters?

Comment: Your curl is ok, review your auth token, and probably you want to use Guzzle, if you are using laravel is already installed